# Changing each column in dataframe in list of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of dataframes, 'mylist', and for each dataframe in that list I want to change the column, 'mycolumn', from factor to character.

I have tried

```
lapply(mylist,"[[", function(x) as.character(x['mycolumn']))
```

which gives the error:

> Error in .subset2(x, ..2, exact = exact) : 
>     invalid subscript type 'closure'

Why do I get the error and how should I do it?

Comment: maybe `lapply(mylist, function(i) {i$mycolumn <- as.character(i$mycolumn); i})`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `transform` to change the specific column to `character`

```
lapply(mylist, transform, mycolumn = as.character(mycolumn))
```